# How to enable speaker and mute over the voice call on button click event from custom UI?

Tags: android, call, android-audiomanager

Let the my question is that i have a custom UI that is invoked whenever there is a voice call incoming or out going. In my ui there are two button speaker and mute. i want to use that button to mute the voice of ongoing call and as well as speaker will be on. How can i achieve this. I also show the UI screenshot of my application.Thanks in advance